# linux driver for uart- overall desgin

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

**hello there I am a newbie coding a driver for a serial PCI based board using 3 16550 UART chips in LINUX.Each uart chip supports 4 channels( 4 serial ports ).

In my Linux driver code i have thought of using threads for each of the ports i.e altogether 4x3=12 ports.Do you think giving a dedicated thread to each of the ports is a good idea,I may use one particular channel to implement a null modem,other channel RS422 some other channel RS485 and so on

The reason I thought for thread programming is that all the threads are to operate independently, and each thread - inturn each port may be active or not in use.So I aim to make them independent of each other as much as possible.

Please let me know how the overall design for this type of driver should be like.Please give links/sources incase such a similar kind is implemented.

This is the first time I am doing such a thing ..is my logic correct / incorrect or just a incorrect flow which is just not valid and sounds absolutely horrible
Thanks and regards**

Comment: Why not take a look at the various serial port driver drivers that are included in the kernel sources? I haven't been messing in those areas of the kernel, but there is surely some framework to jack into. Protocol drivers are best implemented in user space. Having them in the kernel will save you nothing, it would only make your development time longer.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel has a lot of architecture code designed for handling serial IO. As far as I remember, there is no explicit need for threading since notification etc is done by the kernel via callbacks etc. It probably wouldn't hurt to pick up a book about Linux driver development.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that on each port you'll have some protocol running, and in that case a design with 1 thread per port makes a lot of sense IMO, as it allows you to cleanly structure the protocol driver.

We have been using such a design for years, and we use System V messages to connect the protocol threads with the dispatcher/supervisor thread, for historical reasons.  SysV messages are not without their own problems (eg they are not `select()` able), so you might want to have a look at [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870709/how-to-do-asynchronous-inter-thread-communication-on-platform-with-pthreads) for alternatives.

Comment: hello @fvu  thanks for instilling the confidence in me ...can u please share some more links - source codes from where I can get to learn more about this...thanks again

Comment: @user2... sorry the sources I'm referring to are our own material, impossible to publish here.  I'll see what I can find though.